# Drupal timezone calculator

Tags: drupal, timezone

I have a webform in drupal on witch people can ask for a "demo" of my site between 9am and 5 PM in New Yoirk time-zone. My problem is that people from other time zoned don't calculate the time difference and thay ask for demos out of the range.
I am hoping that you guys can suggest me somekind of module for drupal whitch i can use to solve my problem.
If this is not possible, can you please suggest tips how should I solve my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create two modules that contain the content you would.
Publish the current one as and when appropriate.
When you don't want to be approached for demos, unpublish the first block and publish the second block, the one explaining that they need to come back later.

You can look to automate this through the use of crontab and a bash script which calls drush to control the blocks, hiding them / making them appear again.

If you have issues, I'd be happy to take a look at it